# Access ACL entries

Tags: lotus-notes

Somebody can explain why this code won't work. I get no values in the Authors field nor printed anything.

```
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)

    ' Add users with role R* to Authors
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim e As NotesACLEntry
    Dim it As NotesItem

    Set it = Source.Document.GetFirstItem("Authors")

    Set e = s.CurrentDatabase.ACL.GetFirstEntry
    While Not e Is Nothing
        Print e.Name
        If e.IsRoleEnabled("R1") Then it.AppendToTextList(e.Name)
        If e.IsRoleEnabled("R2") Then it.AppendToTextList(e.Name)
        Set e = s.CurrentDatabase.ACL.GetNextEntry(e)
    Wend

End Sub
```

The database is on a server and has entries in the ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are other places in LotusScript where you need to create separate variables like that.  All the examples are written that way.  It's a bug, no doubt, and I doubt it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

I change the code slightly and it works:

```
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)

    ' Add users with role R* to Authors
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim e As NotesACLEntry
    Dim it As NotesItem

    Set it = Source.Document.GetFirstItem("Authors")

    Set acl = s.CurrentDatabase.ACL
    Set e = acl.GetFirstEntry
    Print e Is Nothing
    While Not e Is Nothing
        Print e.Name
        If e.IsRoleEnabled("R1") Then it.AppendToTextList(e.Name)
        If e.IsRoleEnabled("R2") Then it.AppendToTextList(e.Name)
        Set e = acl.GetNextEntry(e)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Is this documented anywhere or simple broken.

Comment: You should update your question rather than put this in an answer

Comment: Yes, this is a problem that occurs when you "chain" methods that rely on state information.  I know I've seen the problem described -- probably by Bob Balaban, either in his old book on programming Domino with Java, or in a presentation.  Don't know if it's in the formal documentation. The first way you wrote it, the ACL object that you used to get the first entry is different from the ACL object that you use to get the next entry so state is lost.  In general for the Notes object classes, you always need to keep your parent objects in scope until you are done with the child objects.

Comment: @Ken, right, but now is too late to move and not remove your comments.